# Dynamics CRM 2011 Microsoft Online CrmSvcUtil Meta Data Contains a Reference that Cannot be Resolved

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online, located here:

https://portal.microsoftonline.com/admin/default.aspx

I am trying to create the dll files from this article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803.aspx

I am having issues running this command:

```
crmsvcutil.exe /url:https://MYORG.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /o:crm.cs /n:Xrm /u:MYUSER@jmawebtechnologies.onmicrosoft.com /p:PASSWORD /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext /di:11y9kv01j1gd2luuzrykbo4c6c /dp:oI=5?M`pVU`@zBeCvw0`ds)4
```

I receive an error saying that meta data contains a reference that cannot be resolved, which I assume is a 404. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the codecustomization part.

However the main question is which CRM Online authentication you need to use.

For CRM Online with `Windows Live ID` authentication is the following command (note `deviceid` and `devicepassword` parameters, the values need to be generated using the utility `deviceregistration` (folder tools\deviceregistration inside the SDK, you need to compile the visual studio project)

> CrmSvcUtil.exe
>   /url:https://organization.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
>                           /username:username /password:pass@word1 /deviceid:abcdefg /devicepassword:1234567890
>                           /out:Xrm.cs /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext

For CRM Online with `Office 365` authentication is this command:

> CrmSvcUtil.exe
>   /url:https://organization.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
>                           /username:username /password:pass@word1
>                           /out:Xrm.cs /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext

Comment: Thanks. This must be added between the .exe and the /url /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"

Comment: that part is not necessary